# React Routing, react-route-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am writing code for dynamically load component when clicking on Link component from react-router-dom.

Data for loading Links.

```
const AsideMenu = [
    {"Title1": [
        {"component": "Comp1", "MenuName": "Comp 1", "id": 1},
        {"component": "Comp2", "MenuName": "Comp 2", "id": 2},
        {"component": "Comp3", "MenuName": "Comp 3", "id": 3},
    ]},
    {"title2": [
        {"component": "Comp 4", "MenuName": "Comp 4", "id": 13},
        {"component": "Comp 5", "MenuName": "Comp 5", "id": 14},
        {"component": "Comp 6", "MenuName": "Comp 6", "id": 15},
    ]}
]

export default AsideMenu;
```

AsideContainer.js

```
const AsideContainer = ({clickMenuIcon, isExpanded}) => {

    const getDropdown = (menu, header, index) => {
        return (
            <div className="nav-menu" key={`${header}_${index}`}>
                <span>{header}</span>
                <Dropdown menu={menu} title={header}/>
            </div>
        )
    }

    return(
        <div className={`sidenav ${isExpanded ? 'expanded' : ''}`} onClick={clickMenuIcon}>
            {AsideMenu.map((item, index) => getDropdown(Object.values(item)[0], Object.keys(item)[0], index))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default AsideContainer;
```

Dropdown.js file

```
import { 
    Link,
    BrowserRouter as Router
} from "react-router-dom";
import "./__dropdown.scss";

const Dropdown = ({menu, title}) => {
    
    return(
        <div className="menu">
            <Router>
                {menu.map((item, index) => <Link to={`/${title && typeof(title) === "string" && title.split(" ").join("")}/${item['component']}/${item['id']}`} 
                    className="menu-item" key={`${item.MenuName}_${index}`}>
                        {item.MenuName}
                    </Link>
                )}
            </Router>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Dropdown;
```

Routes.js File i am writing like:

```
const Routes = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact={true} path="/:title/:component/:id" render={
                    (props) => {
                        console.log(props);
                        return <WrappedComponent {...props} />
                    }
                }>
                </Route>
                <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Home} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default Routes;
```

WrappedComponent is as follow:

```
const WrappedComponent = ({history, location, match}) => {
    const {component} = match.params;
    const LoadableComponent = LazyComponents[component];
    return (
        <ErrorBoundary>
            <Suspense fallback={renderLoading()}>
                <LoadableComponent />
            </Suspense>
        </ErrorBoundary>
    )
}

export default WrappedComponent;
```

Now as I am keep on loading the WrappedComponent only so i am not getting the updated params under match property when cliking on another link although the url is updating. If i will do window.location.href, then i am getting the updated link.
Please suggest

Comment: Please ignore got the root cause.
Was included two Router one in Routes.js and another one for Link wrapping in dropdown.js